# Identify common data using lucene

Tags: lucene

Say I have a system that allows user to manage customer profile. A customer profile may consist of following fields

FirstName
LastName
City
State
Zip
Date of Birth
Employer

For users in a given geographiclocation, the choice of city would mostly be a set of 4-5 local cities. I am trying to save the user from entering the same city or a city from the same set of 4-5 cities.

Is it possible in lucene that given past data, lucene identifies a set of common cities and automatically presents the user a listfor selection

I would like to apply the same logic to other fields like employer. If. City has 2-3 big employers then there is a good chance the new customer works for one if the top 3 employers.

So Imagine user clicks a button that shows most commonly occuring cities and employers. Select the correct option and it fills the fields for you.

Thanks,
A

Comment: This is not the place to post a requirement and get code. What did you already try, where is the problem with that code? Please share what you already have.

Comment: I am not asking for code here. I am asking for the right approach. Approach 1.  Grab all data and run some analytics. But still the question remains what kind of algorithm would make it generic enough. Approach 2. Use lucene facets which I am inclining towards.